# Cordova + GCM -> supported Android versions?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

GCM "requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Google Play Store application installed" (developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

"Cordova supports Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread, starting with Android API level 10) and 4.x." (cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

What Android version are supported by http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.gcm ?
What Android versions are supported by other Cordova GCM plugins?

---

I am asking because I easily got it to work on 4.0, but testing same, very basic code on 2.3 and 4.4.2 I got various errors.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? There have been cases where GCM has problems on certain Android versions or devices.

Comment: will check, but for example android 2.3 did not show any error messages, successfully received reg id, but simply did not receive messages